# How to track down where a dependency comes from in Go modules?

Tags: go, go-modules

I'd have a Go module, say `github.com/myorg/mymodule`, of which I'd like to update the version in another module. However, if I try to `go get -u` it, I get an `unexpected module path` error:

```
> go get -u github.com/myorg/mymodule
go: sourcegraph.com/sourcegraph/go-diff@v0.5.1: parsing go.mod: unexpected module path "github.com/sourcegraph/go-diff"
go get: error loading module requirements
```

The fix for this has been documented at https://github.com/sourcegraph/go-diff/issues/35: this module needs to be imported as `github.com/sourcegraph/go-diff/diff`, not `github.com/sourcegraph/go-diff`.

The problem is, I don't know where to apply this fix - that is, which dependency is importing this sub-dependency the wrong way.

In particular, `go-diff` does not appear in the `go.mod`, it only appears in `go.sum` (in several different modules):

```
> grep go-diff go.mod
> grep go-diff go.sum
github.com/pmezard/go-difflib v1.0.0 h1:4DBwDE0NGyQoBHbLQYPwSUPoCMWR5BEzIk/f1lZbAQM=
github.com/pmezard/go-difflib v1.0.0/go.mod h1:iKH77koFhYxTK1pcRnkKkqfTogsbg7gZNVY4sRDYZ/4=
github.com/sergi/go-diff v1.0.0/go.mod h1:0CfEIISq7TuYL3j771MWULgwwjU+GofnZX9QAmXWZgo=
sourcegraph.com/sourcegraph/go-diff v0.5.0/go.mod h1:kuch7UrkMzY0X+p9CRK03kfuPQ2zzQcaEFbx8wA8rck=
```

I've tried using `go mod why`, but this simply reports that the module is not needed:

```
> go mod why sourcegraph.com/sourcegraph/go-diff
# sourcegraph.com/sourcegraph/go-diff
(main module does not need package sourcegraph.com/sourcegraph/go-diff)
```

What is even more puzzling is that the error message mentions `go-diff@v0.5.1`, whereas the `go.sum` contains `go-diff v0.5.0`.

All in all, how can I track down where this 'mis-import' of the `go-diff` dependency is happening so that I can update my version of that module?

Comment: Run `go mod tidy` to remove unused dependencies. Does it still show up after that?

Comment: I haven't seen this in a while, are you using go1.13?

Comment: It still shows up after `go mod tidy`, and I'm using Go 1.12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to 'patch' this problem by running `go get github.com/sourcegraph/go-diff` and adding this replace directive (cf. https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#when-should-i-use-the-replace-directive) in the module in which I was trying to update the dependency:

```
replace sourcegraph.com/sourcegraph/go-diff => github.com/sourcegraph/go-diff v0.5.1
```

After that, `go get -u github.com/myorg/mymodule` ran without errors.